# Ubuntu 18.04 not emulating windows keystroke configuration correctly when logged into a VM through xrdp

Tags: 18.04, shortcut-keys, virtualization, vmware, remapping

I'm facing some troublesome issues when having a user use ubuntu's (18.04) xrdp app to remote into a VM. They are logging into a windows based vm being ran by VMWare.

The connection and multi-monitor works as desired but once they're logged into the VM, the keyboard shortcuts in windows conflict with the ubuntu shortcuts, i.e. Ctrl + C in linux kills the process but the user needs to be able to copy and paste in the windows VM as they'll be responsible for data entry.
Additionally, the 10-key number pad operates fine in the ubuntu desktop but once the user logs into the VM, it goes dead but only for the VM. If they log out and type in the ubuntu desktop, the input is registering.

How can i remap the linux keystrokes to match windows and how do i get the 10-key up and running again?

I apologize in advance if this is an easy work around, I'm not very intimate with ubuntu or linux.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone has this problem, below is the terminal command that resolved the  error of VMWare  not acknowledging the 10 key pad:

echo 'xkeymap.nokeycodeMap = true' > ~/.vmware/config

The other issue of windows key config was resolved after running this code and restarting the PC. I cant validate whether the above line was what fixed it or not.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! You are correct, i miss copied the line when pasting it here. I updated the answer to reflect the accurate info.